# what is the best creational pattern to apply for class to access different databases

Tags: python, design-patterns

i have an application written in python

currently there are around 5 classes that are used to access different databases.

Structure of these classes are like below (i know it is poorly designed):

```
class access_db_a:
      def __init__(self, db):
          self.mydb = None
      def connect(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=info["db_2_host"],
        user=info["user"],
        passwd=info["passwd"],
        database=info["db_2"],
        )
      def select(self):
          mycursor = mydb.cursor()
          mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(TABLE_NAME))
          myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
          for x in myresult:
              print(x)
      def insert(self):
          mycursor = mydb.cursor()
          query = {'queries for db'}

class access_db_b:
      def __init__(self, db_2):
          self.mydb = None
      def connect(self, db_2):        
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=info["db_2_host"],
        user=info["user"],
        passwd=info["passwd"],
        database=info["db_2"],
        )
      def select(self):
          mycursor = mydb.cursor()
          mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(TABLE_NAME))
          myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
          for x in myresult:
              print(x)
      def insert(self):
          mycursor = mydb.cursor()
          query = {'queries for db_2'}
```

My question is: what is the best creational design pattern to apply here (i.e. Signleton, Factory Method)? the purpose is to minimize the duplication

Comment: The `class` has `self` while the methods don't? You should base your question on a *working* example.

Comment: @KlausD.code updated

Comment: These classes look exactly the same to me... Are they different at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga classes work on different DBs. i do not want to put any information about the schema here. thats why they look all the same.

Comment: @CCCCos don't hard-code that information into your class, use one class and pass those as arguments to your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to define a base class for mysql. This class can be separated in a file, maybe as your own library.

```
class mysqlBase():
    def __init__(self, host, user, passwd, database):
        self.host       = host
        self.user       = user
        self.passwd     = passwd
        self.database   = database
        self.db         = None

    def connect(self,):
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host        = self.host,
            user        = self.user,
            passwd      = self.passwd,
            database    = self.database,
            )

    def select(self, tbl):
        mycursor = self.db.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(tbl))
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in myresult:
            print(x)

    # more functions
    # ...
```

then use it in your classes

```
class access_db_a():
    def __init__(self, host, user, passwd, database):
        self.mydb = mysqlBase(host, user, passwd, database)

    def connect(self,):
        self.mydb.connect()

    def select(self, tbl):
        self.mydb.select(tbl)

    # more functions refer to mysqlBase()
    # ...
```

or with class inheritance,

```
class access_db_a(
        mysqlBase
        ):
    def __init__(self, host, user, passwd, database):
        mysqlBase.__init__(self, host, user, passwd, database)

    # No need to define connect(), unless you wanna override it
    # No need to define select(),  unless you wanna override it
```

finally, in your code, call your class as object.

```
# Const
info = {                         # just some database const
    'A': {
        "host": "192.128.0.123",
        "id": "AAA",
        "pw": "aaa",
        "db": "whatever",
    },
}
dbA = access_db_a(**info['A'])   # pass the login detail to your class
dbA.connect()
dbA.select('TABLE_A')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. If you are trying to call those definitions on the databases, you need to define them. As is they don't do anything. If they are functions that already exist in the python library or another module, then you don't need to put them in a class at all. You can just call them on the databases after you define them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. If you are trying to call those definitions on the databases, you need to define them. As is they don't do anything. If they are functions that already exist in the python library or another module, then you don't need to put them in a class at all. You can just call them on the databases after you define them.

Also, if you are trying to make the functions to be attributes of the class, then you need an `__init__()` constructor function. like this:

```
class access_db_a():
     def __init__(self):
         self.connect = connect()
         self.select = select()
         self.insert = insert()
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. let me rephrase my question. i have like 5 classes similar to this. all have similar functions like connect/select/insert. i would like to rewrite them to have as less duplication as possible. for example, i can create an abstract class and let these classes inherit from the abstract class. i want to know if this is a good idea to do so

Comment: ok so use class inheritance. when you define the class, have it inhereit from the class you want to duplicate. It will automatically have all the same properties. it looks like this.

Comment: `class copyCat(Cat):

Comment: cat is the class that it will inherit from

Comment: dont put that little tick before class, that was a type error